# Error in importing wordpress xml

Tags: import, xml, uploads

Iam trying to import my old xml to a newly installed wordpress(3.0.1), the max upload size shows 0, `i tried uploading it, but it ended up with empty screen. How should i proceed?`

Answer (score 1):

White screen is a PHP error.

Check your server's error_log and see if there's anything helpful, but you may not have permissions on PHP set up correctly to upload.

(Also you should try doing this on 3.2.1 and not a two-major-release back version)